# NSPredicate - filtering values based on a BOOLEAN stored value

Tags: iphone, xcode, nspredicate, boolean

I have a core data model object called Entry.
In this I have an attribute IsFavorite.

I would like to use an NSPredicate to filter the results of my NSFetchedResultsController.

Currently I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the fetch executes.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate. 

NSEntityDescription *thisEntry = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entry" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];
[fetchRequest setEntity:thisEntry];

NSPredicate *fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Entry.isFavorite == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


NSError *error = nil;
if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSlog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

IF I remove the line that sets the predicate on the fetchRequest, my code executes perfectly.

I am clearly n00bin out on the predicate but have had much trouble trying to find out how to perform operations on a BOOLEAN value from a core data model object.  It is noted that there are answers on how to do this with a string or int value but I can't find a BOOLEAN example.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This isn't really specific to NSPredicate... Whenever you have `%@` in a format string, the corresponding value must be a pointer to an object, and BOOL doesn't qualify.  So instead of passing YES, pass `[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]`.

---

In newer versions of Xcode and the SDKs than when I originally wrote the answer, you can use `@YES` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]`.

Comment: I've updated my code above - which still crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS :(

Will it be Entity.Attribute =? as I have written? or just the Attribute =?

Comment: This worked for me if I used the NSNumber description like this
`[[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] description];`

Comment: @T. Markle The `description` method is called when `stringWithFormat` asks an object for its string representation. You should be able to use the `NSNumber` instance without that `description` call.

Answer (score 37):

From Apple's documentation:

> Boolean Values
>
> You specify and test for equality of Boolean values as illustrated in the following examples:

```
NSPredicate *newPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:aBool]];
NSPredicate *testForTrue =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == YES"];
```

However, something that caught me out:

Be sure to untick the `Optional` entity attribute and set a `Default Value` of `YES` or `NO`, otherwise the column will be empty (null?) and the above predicates will not match rows which are not explicitly set.

I used the great app sqllitebrowser to diagnose this one, by looking at the resulting simulator database.

Comment: Sorry @János I don't know much Swift yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing to "Be sure to untick the Optional entity attribute". Saved my hours!

Comment: Glad to help! I spent hours on it... now I pay more attention to that right-hand panel, I'd kind of ignored it till then.

Comment: Me too, before yesterday :)

Comment: Non optional booleans fixed a big problem i was having.  seems to me that checking for  boolAttribute != YES should work, but it didn't until i set default values on the field

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the Optional and default value, you saved my day!

Answer (score 26):

If you know you're looking for a YES (and therefore don't need to switch between YES or NO in different situations), this worked for me:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFavorite == 1"]
```

Comment: it should be for a dynamic value.

Comment: @KETAN If you know you're looking for YES, then @"isFavorite == YES" will work.

Comment: i think you should use "%@", @YES

Answer (score 4):

For me, on **SWIFT 3.0** use NSNumber and %@ didn't work, I had to use integer values:

```
NSPredicate(format: "yourAttributeName == %i", yourBooleanValue ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

swift 3 version worked great for me:

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isFriend == %@" ,NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false))
```

following @scipilot answer the bool shouldn't be an optional. thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly if you "know" which one you want, you can just have:

```
let p = NSPredicate(format: "showMe == true")
```

example,

```
let r = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CDThing")
let p = NSPredicate(format: "showMe == true")
r.predicate = p
```

You would do this for things like "subscribed", "new" etc.

Answer (score 0):

on iOS 10, xcode 9.0, looking for a core data managedObject with Boolean NO attribute:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attributeName == nil"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check nil OR false

If you didn't set value before , it may come into nil category even if Bool data type

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isDeviceLine == nil OR isDeviceLine == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isComplete LIKE[c] %@)",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]];
```