# TableViewCell - Gather ManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

my question is regarding a specific "problem" where I am struggling since hours.

I am having a custom cell (`ViewController` is `ToDoCellVC`) in `TableViewController` "`ToDoVC`" filled with 2 elements *"Title"* and *"Date"*.

When I select the cell and delete it -> its working.

But I am also having two buttons inside each cell who should perform 2 actions:

- **Information Button** : Display Alert by fetching data from Cell including the Name inside the `ManagedObject` (`Entity: ToDoItems;` which is not displayed) and then with the name doing a predicate for another entity (which is working already)
- **Add to other `TVC` and delete from current TVC** : This action should delete the actual data from `ToDoVC` and move it to `DoneVC` which has another entity "`DoneRecords`" with the same attributes.

I think I could accomplish the code by myself if I found a method to gather information about current cell using `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: I would suggest you add a `Bool` attribute to your `ToDoItems` entity (some might refer to this as a "flag") called `completed` or `done`. Based on whether it's 'true` or `false` would determine which TVC it's displayed in. It sounds like you don't want to delete your item--you want to display it in either `toDoTVC` or `doneTVC` based on that flag.

Comment: Thank you Adrian for your comment. Basically I want to delete from toDoTVC (Entity ToDoItems) and display/add to Entiry DoneRecords which are displayed on DoneTVC.

Comment: I would have an called `myToDoItem` with a `Bool` attribute called `isDone` that can be set to `true` or `false`. Then you'd just configure one TVC to display `myToDoItem.isDone` for true and another TVC that displays for false.

Comment: So you mean I should assign "isDone" as Bool to my attributes in Entity and check if bool is true or false...I understand that fact perfectly. And I am sure this will work. In my case I need to fetch the information regarding the actual item...because when fetching I get nil data or my app crashed

Comment: Exactly. When you create your `ToDoItem` object w/ the `isDone` attribute, set it to `false` initially. It'll show up in the TVC you've got configure to display uncompleted ToDoItems. When want to mark it done, you'd just reset the `isDone` attribute to `false`, save to your `managedObjectContext`, and reload the `tableView`.

Comment: I tried it. My table is filling with the "true" items. But when I click the button...i renamed to "setFalse" for test the app crashes. or it says that the output is nil. I need to get information about the row...since the row nor the data is selected...simply the button inside the row is clicked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having 2 separate entities for your `ToDoList`, I would have one entity with an `isDone` Boolean attribute.

- Cells on your `ToDoTVC` would display objects where `isDone` is `false`

and

- Cells on your `DoneTVC` would display objects where `isDone` is `true`.

When you create your `ToDoListItem`, set its initial value to false.

Here's a post on using `NSPredicates` you'll find helpful for populating your `TableViewControllers`.

[NSPredicate - filtering values based on a BOOLEAN stored value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445431/nspredicate-filtering-values-based-on-a-boolean-stored-value)